# What is causing a voltage drop on the 5v power rail on this bench setup?

Tags: power-supply, voltage

I am testing a video card and because I need to probe the logic chips on the 5V circuit I thought about hooking it up to my bench PSU. I am powering and measuring on the ISA pins where 5V and GND are exposed.
The card has convenient headers for those

- So bench supply is connected to B1 (GND) and B3 (+5v)
- Multimeter is checking voltage on B31 (GND) and B29 (+5v)

What I noticed was that I am seeing a very low voltage on the power rail when it is powered like that.
(I did the same with another videocard and I had the same readings).So that makes me think the issue is not related to the videocard itself. The PSU keeps saying 5.08V, so I don't see the voltage drop there. But I am seeing it with my multimeter.

When attached to a computer, that voltage drop on the power rail is not there, as it keeps outputting a clean 5V wen measuring with the same multimeter.

Why exactly is causing this on the bench setup ? I know that when something is shorting that I typically see it on the bench PSU (the voltage drops to almost zero). Here this is not the case as it remains on 5.08V and sees a steady current. Bot when measuring I only get 3.1v, meaning that all the logic chips also only get 3.1v so not really representative as a test.

[image]

Comment: If you are using cheap Chinese wires, they act more like resistors and less like wires. I had same problems, not knowing that these colored wires/cables were incredibly thin inside and of high resistance; you could literally use them as resistors, that's how bad they are. It's amazing to me how they even manage to make them of such a high resistance at such short lengths; I guess it's the incredible art of dirt-cheap crap-making.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem: the series resistance of wires and contact resistances.

It looks to me that 1.24 A is flowing. You're using **crock-clips, thin wires** with "fragile" breadboard type connectors. That can easily cause a significant voltage drop at that current.

Confirm that by measuring at the supply output directly (you should get 5 V), then at the banana-crock clips (you will still get about 5 V), then at the crock-clip-thin wire (I guess you will get 4 V), then at the gold contacts on the card. Each measurement will give a lower voltage.

I suggest to **solder** some wire to the +5 V and ground rails, for example in parallel with one of the many decoupling capacitors on the card. Then make a solid connection from those wires to the supply. Maybe the supply has screw terminals, then use those. Prevent clips, connectors and contacts as much as possible.

Comment: 4.8v on start of crock-clip, 3.7v on the end of the crock-clip, 3.3v on the card .... wow ... did not know that would make such a huge difference. Never noticed that when playing around with Arduino's because current was a lot lower. Thanks a lot !